# Routing library for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, routes, backbone.js

I used to use Backbone.js as an easy MVC framework which have build-in routing support. Now I have moved and currently using Agility.js which doesn't routing support. So my question is, is there any alternative to Backbones.js's routing?

For reference on why I need this is because my "style" of writing is a one-page website that query the server for information.

Comment: I would love to know a place this question is constructive, because it is to me.

Comment: I agree what the hell is going on with stack... most of the decent question i come across are closed???

Comment: Asking for frameworks / libraries that perform a certain function is absolutely productive and is a large part or what stack overflow is. I am very disheartened that this question was closed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've faced the same question just some weeks ago and wrote "Simrou", a very basic framework that does nothing but this kind of routing (hash-based). You can define the routes in Backbone's own style and then attach action handlers to GET, POST, PUT etc. requests (GET is basically a clicked link, POST etc. can be triggered by forms).

https://github.com/buero-fuer-ideen/Simrou

Comment: This looks very promising, I will wait for other answer for a while because you just wrote this "some weeks ago" and I'm working on a very large project. So if no one answer with a better solution I will accept your answer. Looks very promising btw.

Comment: That is probably the best you can do - we used this framework in a medium sized project and it performed very well. But it is indeed absolutely simple and does not provide very much functionality. You may want to take a look at Sammy.js btw!

Comment: Sammy.js is not for me. I already got my MVC fixed(Agility.js) and I will use your library :) very nicely done. Very flexible.

Comment: Thank you! If you run into anything that does not working as expected or could be solved better, please let me know.

Comment: This looks very interesting @Niko! What about tests though?

Comment: Thanks @ggozad! I must confess that I didn't worry about tests up to now. Haven't ever done this with javascript, can you recommend any framework/whatever?

Comment: @Niko use QUnit (if I remember correctly), also for improving Simrou  `var registerRoute = function(pattern, getAction, >>>putAction<<<, ...)` I will edit and push it to you.

Comment: @Niko I use jasmine which I find clean and concise...

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what sort of features you are looking for, but I just put up an extremely lightweight JS router that offers the bare minimum to get things going.  A lot of the routers I had come across were offering way more features than I was looking for, so I thought this might help fill a void for those looking for something light.  It defaults to use pushState, falls back to hash. http://gabehayes.github.com/lennonjs/.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [Davis.js](http://davisjs.com) it provides simple routing, based on pushState (it can work with hash based routing also).  It is inspired by Sammy.js but only focuses on the routing side.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14096633/change-to-davis-js-routing-lib