# change to davis.js routing lib

Tags: jquery

I use pushstate/popstate build a demo, but I'm wondering **if Davis.js js routing lib how to use here, can anyone help me for below example?**
Thanks!!

**with davis.js** index.php

```
print"<a class=\"a\" href=\"$result[id]\"></a>";
if($_GET['id']){
    if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest'){
        print"
            <div class=\"wrapb\">
                <div class=\"b\"></div>
                <div class=\"close\"></div>
            </div>
        ";
    }
}
```

js

```
var app = Davis(function(){
    this.get('?id=:name', function(req){
        var b = $(req).filter('.wrapb').html();
            $('.a').before(b);
            $('.close').click(function(){
                history.back();
            });
    })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do what you are trying to acheive:

```
var app = Davis(function () {
  this.get('/', function (req) {
    var xhr = $.ajax('/', {
      data: { id: req.params.id },
      dataType: 'html'
    })

    xhr.then(function (data) {
      var html = $(data)

      html.find('.close').on('click', function () {
        history.back()
      })

      $('.a').before(html)
    })
  })
})
```

The `req` object that is yielded to the route handler is not an ajax request, it is an object representing the 'request' to the path, in this case `/`, more from the [docs](http://olivernn.github.com/davis.js/docs/#Request).

You have to do any work that you want to happen when a link is clicked inside the route callback, in your case it looks like you want to make a request to the server which will respond with a snipped of html (I'm not a PHP developer so this may be wrong).  You then want to append this html after a link in the current document.

Davis isn't designed to allow routing based on query params so you shouldn't use them in the path defintion, so I changed it to just `/`.